# Problems to use basic performance counters with my WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7, performancecounter

**Hi,**

I have a service as follows :

- WCF (.NET framework 4.0)
- Hosted in IIS7
- Per Session based service
- TCP communication with no security
- MessageInspectors to log and handle user(login/logout/cache) on both
  client and service
- Winform Client that uses channel factory to communicate with service

To enable performance counters I have added the following to the web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
```

In Performance monitor i have the following entries :

- ServiceModelService 4.0.0.0
- ServiceModelOperation 4.0.0.0
- ServiceModelEndPoint 4.0.0.0

Under ServiceModelService I can see one instance and thats my WCF service hosted in IIS7, if I add Calls and Calls duration and then OK I will still not get any drawings in the Performance Monitor even when running my client against the service? I have tried to use "Scale selected counters" but I still do not see anything?

If I check the ServiceModelOperation I can somtimes see my operations but even if I add a couple of these counters I will not get any read in the Performance Monitor?

ServiceModelEndPoint do never show any instances so no counters can be added?

If I however add the Instances counter under ServiceModelService, this will give me a reading but thats it.

**Pleas help, why am I not getting any performance counters to show up?**

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9518223/130352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of work it showed that two service method names was the problem. I dont really see why but then changing them slightly it worked. And no its not any problems with response/request och attributes, all I really needed to do was to change the name a bit.

The name is not a ".net name" but maby it was to long and to similar to another service method name.

Comment: Hi @Banshee I have the same issue like yours I can't get values for my counters ( service and operations ones) when the performanceCounters="All", actually I added Calls and calls duration counter and invoke my service but in vain no data are displayed. However, when I change performanceCounters="ServiceOnly" I 'm able to get all counter values but only for services. I check if I have duplicate instance names for operations but all are unique. Any help plz.