# Not all WCF performance counters showing up for service instances on Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-server-2008-r2, performancecounter

Long time lurker first time poster. Well I've spent a day researching this & couldn't find any leads so here's hoping people far more intelligent than me have run into this before.

Currently we have handful of .NET 4 WCF services hosted within windows services running on **Windows Server 2003**. When going to perfmon they are all showing up under ServiceModelService 4.0.0.0 as expected. However when these same services are being run on **Windows Server 2008 R2** only a few instances are being displayed. The hosting services are all running and performing as expected, just we are unable to get any perfomance counter information as the instances are not all listed under each counter.

The same occurs for ServiceModelEndPoint 4.0.0.0 & ServiceModelOperation 4.0.0.0.

I've tried reinstalling the counters via lodctr /r 
& lodctr /M:ServiceModelPerformanceCounters.man.
Tried repairing the .NET 4 installation on the server.

There are no errors in the Event log indicating any issue with the counters or allocated memory.

All app.config files 
`<diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true" performanceCounters="All" />`

The only thing I have found is that on Windows Server 2008 R2 the registry only has entries for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ServiceModelEndpoint 3.0.0.0`
 & no mention of 4.0.0.0 (same for the other two ServiceModel* counters) as we only have VM's built off the same image I haven't been able to verify if this is expected or a problem has occurred during installation.

So what I am hoping for is someone to either confirm that the installation is corrupt (I have been unable to find information on the registry settings in 2008) or why not all the WCF service instances are showing up in perfmon

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9518223/130352